# How does JSON work when calling from Postman (or SoapUI)?

Tags: json, rest, postman

I'm using **Postman** and sending various requests that get responses in `XML` or `JSON`. I want to understand *how* `JSON` works with the APIs. I know that `JSON` is a called response and I know how to write a `JSON` file and read it and understand it, although I've never actually used it.

So, my question is how does `JSON` show up on the website?
I imagine someone has to code it there, similar to `HTML`.

When I google, I just basically get `how-to` instructions on various tools from a procedural standpoint and nothing relevant to my question.

Comment: Search for HTTP Accept Header and learn about content negotiation through the HTTP Protocol.

Comment: @JuliePixie: I guess you need to clarify on **How JSON works with the APIs?** here. `JSON` is a data format like `XML` or any other format. Is your question about how the server understands that it is receiving a `JSON` body in the request i.e. [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) and [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) headers? You have to be a bit more specific. As for the rendering, the browser does the rendering of `HTML`, `JSON` and any other format that it supports.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table - You might get some idea.How they are using json in html.

Comment: Azeem yes, exactly. I think I'm wondering how the browser does the rendering, what steps happen for the JSON to be rendered on the page. My boss is asking for this clarification and unfortunately he's giving me even less information than I'm giving you and won't elaborate. I'll try rgdayo and Sudha's suggestions though